# Capybara: How do I test that a table has 3 rows using Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

How do I test that a table has 3 rows using Capybara?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
page.should have_selector('table tr', :count => 3)
```

you can also do minimum or maximum

```
page.should have_selector('table tr', :minimum => 3)
```